# I want to get the maximum number in a particular column of sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint

Below is the query that I am trying

```
 SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
 query.RowLimit = 1;
 query.Query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Identifier' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>";
 SPListItemCollection Items = list.GetItems(query);
 if (Items.Count > 0)
 {
 SPListItem item = Items[0];
 maxValue = (int)item["Identifier"];
 }
```

This is the error that I am getting **strong text**Specified cast is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

What type is the "Identifier" column? It's not a field of [SPListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx) so I'm assuming it is the name of a column in your list.

Try:

```
var tempVal = item["Identifier"];
```

then put a breakpoint there and see what Visual Studio tells you about the structure and type of that item.

Comment: I was able to fix it..maxValue= Convert.toInt32(item["Identifier"]);